How to ensure Nuxt/Vue renders empty alt attributes as alt="" for accessibility?
I'm working with Nuxt 3 and NuxtImg, and there's an issue where empty alt attributes on images are rendered as just alt without the expected quotes and empty value. This is a significant accessibility concern, as alt and alt="" are not interpreted the same way by assistive technologies.
Directly binding the empty string in the template <img :alt='""'/> does not work. So I tried setting the attribute programmatically after the component has mounted, using both a ref and by selecting the element directly from the document. I also tried using nextTick() and setTimeout() to bypass Vue's optimization that appears to strip out the empty string, however the rendered html always has just alt.

One or the other just seems meh anyway, why don't you put an actual alt text? Also, how is it different from a reader's perspective? Having no description or an empty one?

Thanks for the response! So i'm hoping to find a solution because according the WCAG alt="" should be used for an image that is decorative so it's ignored by screen readers. I could put alt text in for all images as you suggested, but the guidelines say not to do this so you avoid creating "audible clutter to screen reader output." . Just alt is read as a missing attribute and so browsers read the file name (or the url) which is, according to WCAG, "not an option."

Ooooh, makes sense! Then, don't you have an HTML attribute to skip the screen-reader whatsoever? I guess that you could fix it on Vue's side, maybe a Vite setting to set? Maybe if you set :alt="false" (or maybe null)? I saw it somewhere on some Github issues long time ago so I guess there is either a specific syntax or a bundler flag possible.

Yeah, I could set aria-hidden='true' - that would work but it feels kinda hacky, i'd love to just get the attribute set right. Settting :alt='null' will remove the alt prop completely, but I'll look into the Vite settings, maybe there's something there. Thanks for the suggestions!

Very interesting question. Apparently Vue strips down the value of attributes with empty value and deletes them if the value is null or undefined. It must do this by checking the value length after ruling out null|undefined. The only nullish value that could get past this check is the null character \0. Incidentally it worked.

I love this, Igor, thank you! It totally works, though it's also a little hacky and it only seems to work if you are setting attribute explicitly - if you try set the alt dynamically the null character gets rendered as unknown  �.
